# working with onkeypress event issue

Tags: javascript

This code is working in IE but not in Chrome:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="txtFirstName"  
       class="txtbox" 
       onkeypress="charsCapsSpaceOnly()" 
       maxlength="30" 
       onpaste="return false" 
       autocomplete='off'> </td>

 function charsCapsSpaceOnly() {
     event.keyCode = event.keyCode - 32;
     if( ((event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90)) || (event.keyCode == 32)) { 
         event.keyCode = event.keyCode;
     } else {
         event.keyCode=0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Try reading the helpful pop-ups before slapping a tag on a question.  This has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: Have you looked at Chrome's debugger?  Are there any errors?  On which lines?

Comment: It's not a very good idea to modify the elements on the `event` object. I suggest you try with `var key = event.keyCode - 32` (and change all following `event.keyCode` to `key`).

Answer (score 1):

This works in both IE9 and Chrome.

```
 function charsCapsSpaceOnly() 
 {
     if (!( ((event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90)) || (event.keyCode == 32)) )
     {
         event.keyCode=0;            // For IE
         event.preventDefault();     // For chrome
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the keycode you will have to use this:

```
function (event){
    var keyCode = !event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode,
    key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    ....
}
```

Because IE is different from other browsers (They want to feel special :)) )